Is 'argue whether' natural?

Lawyers argue whether the Constitution’s ‘insurrection’ clause blocks
Trump from the 2024 ballot.

'argue whether' is really rare. But ,this sentence is from Los Angeles Times.

It sounds natural to me. I checked your ngram and don't understand why you're comparing two phrases with completely different meanings.

@Peter Kirkpatrick To highlight "rare", "unclear that" is already rare, "argue whether" is lower than it.

OK, but a rare word can still be a completely natural word. Is that the only reason you have for this question? I repeat, this is natural and correct to me. If you have a concern, what would you say differently?

I agree with @Peter Kirkpatrick that argue whether sounds natural.
There are lot of hits in Google Books and also 16 exact matches in Ludwig.  Ludwig says

it is used when presenting a statement or question that requires a debating or discussing of a particular topic or issue.


Many students argue whether school uniforms should be mandatory.


Commentators argue whether this "typical" Englishman was overemotional or repressed.


Native speakers would understand what "argue whether" means; it would be understood as synonymous with "debate whether". It has a long history of several hundred years. But some speakers might find it awkward and think "argue over whether" sounds more natural. For those speakers, we  "argue {a position}" and "argue over {whether such-and-such is the case}". argue over whether arose in the 20th century and began to take bites of argue whether's lunch.

Good explanation of the history and alternative.
